# Accounting Software for Ubuntu other than GnuCash?

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

I have performed numerous searches looking for accounting software for Linux (I am running Ubuntu) and haven't found any good solutions.  Maybe I am glossing over something?

I have been using GnuCash for years after dropping Moneydance.  I don't remember exactly why I stopped using it, probably for reasons similar to my wanting to get away from GnuCash. Plus, it isn't open-source and I didn't want to buy a product that I hadn't been satisfied with in the first place.

The problems I have with GnuCash are the constant errors I have in reconciliation.  Every statement is a wrestling match of importing data, matching data, transactions not being imported, account totals changing after a reconciliation, math errors and on and on.  Plus, I have tried to find support but there is little to be had; I have tried to get on the mailing list a couple of times with no success.

I am a sole proprietor of a business and own property so I have multiple accounts to handle.  I need accounting software mostly for year-end P&L statements for income tax preparation for my accountant.

If you have any suggestions, I'd love to hear about them.  GnuCash has pretty much worn me out, so I need to find something else.

Comment: if it aint listed here don't bother looking anywhere else: https://alternativeto.net/software/gnucash/ the lists on that website are extensive, "The problems I have with GnuCash are the constant errors I have in reconciliation" why not focus on getting that sorted? numerous people use gnucash and I doubt all of them have these kind of problems.

Comment: suggestions on how to get it sorted?  I have difficulty finding help for GnuCash.  I use dozens - maybe hundreds -  of programs, this is the only one where I can't find answers to my questions.

Comment: You don't say whether you have consideration for local taxes (such as Value Added) or even which tax regime you are in which may well influence decisions about which product will meet your needs.

Comment: Also, much thanks for the list of alternatives.  I am hoping Grisbi works out if only because it is French slang for "loot" :)  I finally got on the GnuCash mailing list as well.